# delete function using ajax in yii

Tags: ajax, yii

am new for YII. i custom table created displayed tables values while update the form. so i want to update the form. when i click to delete button the row wants to be delete. i wrote delete query which is

```
![i added screen shot. which shows del button. if click entire row wants to be delete][1]
```

In this query. entire tables gets deleted when am refresh page.. please suggest me suitable answer

```
 $id =$_REQUEST['id'];
        $id1=10;
         $command ="DELETE FROM holidays WHERE holiday_id='$id' and recipe_id='$id1'";
   $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($command);
      $command->execute();
```

Comment: please post your full controler code

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the "Yii way".

```
// Load the entity
$holiday = Holiday::model()->findByPk($_REQUEST['id']);

// delete entity
$holiday->delete();
```

Read [Working with Database](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.overview)  for details.

A good example of deleting by AJAX is included in the gii-generated code. You can create a delete link by

```
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("delete",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))
```

and the controller then deletes the entity by this function

```
public function actionDelete($id) {
    if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsPostRequest()) {
        $this->loadModel($id, 'Holiday')->delete();

        if (!Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
    } else
        throw new CHttpException(400, Yii::t('app', 'Your request is invalid.'));
}
```

Comment: how to pass the ajax value in script

Comment: how to add the ajax option <script>
    function change(x,y){
  
  
  
    $.ajax({
     url: <?php Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("holidays/holidaydelete",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey));?>,
     type: 'POST',
      //   async: false,

     data: 'DELETE id from holidays where id=$id',
     
   });
       
        
    }
</script>